# Get file modification date in MM-DD-YYYY format without time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get only the date in a certain format from a file. I was able to get it working using the following code, but it gives the time, as well as the formatting is incorrect.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Code**

```
modDate = os.stat(fPath).st_mtime
        print(datetime.fromtimestamp(modDate))
```

**Output:**

> 2018-03-01 15:48:30.149375

Comment: Why are you expecting that to only print the date? And what format is expected?

Comment: @jhpratt I did not expect the above code to display only the date. I tried other code, such as datetime.date, and all that resulted in errors. To prevent confusion I reverted the code to the above. All I am trying to get from the output is the date in the format MM-DD-YYYY